# How to prevent the debugger from running after build failure in VS Code?

Tags: c++, configuration, visual-studio-code

I want the debugger not to be started when there are compilation errors in the code. This situation occurs when I have a successful build, then I make some changes that do not compile, and when I am launching the debugger, build fails, but the debugger is still launched with an old executable.

I know about `Features -> Debug -> On task errors` option, but it does not change this behavior.

I have the latest version of VS Code on Windows, standard C++ extension and mingw.
This is my pretty much standard configuration:

`.code-workspace`

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": ".."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "debug.onTaskErrors": "abort"
    }
}
```

`launch.json`

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "D:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe debug build"
        },
    ]
}
```

`tasks.json`

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe debug build",
            "command": "D:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": ["-std=c++17","-Wall","-Wextra","-D","LOCAL","-g","${file}","-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: \"D:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe\""
        },
    ]
}
```

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Don't click the run anyway button when the build fails.

Comment: Run your compilation task only and don't attempt to also run the debugger at all.

Comment: @sweenish, sorry, but I don't understand what 'run anyway' button are you talking. I remember something like this in Visual Studio but never saw this in Visual Studio Code. I just want to press `F5` and build and run my code, I don't want to do it separately.

Answer (score 0):

I create a script, it delete the binary first, then run compile.

If build fail, new exe will not exists, debugger will fail to start.